# combine one string column to another with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If i have a following dataframe:

```
id     categories      products
01        fruit       Apple, Apricot
02        fruit       Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03        fruit       Orange, Pineapple, Pear
04      vegetable     Carrot, Cabbage
```

and i want create a new df like this, what i should do? thanks.

```
id          products
01     (fruit)Apple, Apricot
02     (fruit)Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03     (fruit)Orange, Pineapple, Pear
04     (vegetable)Carrot, Cabbage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    df = df.set_index('id')
    df  =df.apply(lambda x: "(" + x['categories'] + ")" + x['products'],axis=1).to_frame('products')
    print df
```

Comment: At this point, why not just `'(' + x.categories + ')' + x.products`?

Comment: to maintain 'id'

Comment: You can still do that; it seems that the direct approach is both simpler and more efficient than using `apply`.

Answer (score 4):

Just sum strings

```
"(" + df.categories + ")" + df.products
```

Comment: do you know why `df['format'] = '({0}){1}'.format(df.categories, df.products)` doesn't work in that way?

Comment: @aydow because you will be getting the result of the conversion of the arguments (in this case, the `Series` objects `df.categories` and `df.products`) to `string` and replacing it in the` {0}` and `{1}`. The result will be a single string and not a series as you probably intended